# csv files broken

Tags: php, excel, csv

```
/* generate csv content */

while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))         {
        /* If two or more columns of the result have the same field names, the last column will take precedence. */
        for($i=0; $i<mysql_num_fields($query);$i++)             {
                $data = $res[mysql_field_name($query,$i)];
                $data = trim( preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $data ) );
                echo "\"".$data."\";";
        }
        echo "\r\n";
}
```

The following code intends to remove extra whitespace or newline characters and generate a csv file. My problem is that on some workstations the csv file is displayed correctly and on other stations it is displayed incorrectly although all stations have the same Regional and Language Settings.

Is there something else I should check out or use a different code for generating proper csv files that cleans hidden spaces or new lines?

#### LATER EDIT

I discovered some faulty settings regarding regional and language settings options, although the settings we're the same, in Regional Options > Customise > Numbers > List Separator it was something different from ";" so this explains some of the issues reported.

The fix is to implement proper csv code generator and check workstation configurations.

Comment: Define `displayed incorrectly`... When displayed in which piece of software? In what way is it wrong? Are all stations Windows? Because if not, that `\r\n` may the thing that's causing the problem...

Comment: all stations are windows, as far as I am concerned on MS \r\n and \n are parsed the same, am i wrong?

Comment: Most pieces of software on most platforms can cope with any line ending style. However, one notable exception is Notepad on Windows - this only understands `\r\n`. Another one is that some versions of `vi`/`vim` on Linux only understand `\n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$outfp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  foreach ($row as &$field) {
    $field = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($field));
  }
  fputcsv($outfp, $row, ';');
}
```

Using [`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) will produce much better output than anything you can write manually, considering many edge cases that your code does not. You can write it to [`php://output`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) and it will be the same as `echo`ing it.

Comment: on test instance it looks promising, still waiting for tests on production environment, will accept the answer after tests

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
for ($i=0; $i<mysql_num_fields($query); $i++)
```

it should be

```
for ($i=0; $i<mysql_num_fields($res); $i++)
```

to look at the correct number of fields.

Comment: i'm using $query because i need to show duplicate columns in some resultsets